# Как проверить данные на уникальность в базе данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть БД `PostgreSQL 14`, с сервиса приходят данные, их нужно записывать в таблицу, если определенных 3 сразу столбцов уже нет в базе данных, подскажите, как это лучше реализовать? `UNIQUE` для этой задачи не подходит, т.к, по одному столбцы могут повторяться.

Comment: а postgreSQL позволяем сделать ключ из трех полей? select distinct a,b,c вернет уникальные сочетания трех полей

Comment: А если UNIQUE на 3 поля? `ALTER TABLE someTable ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3)`?

Comment: Да тут даже простой запрос подойдет вида `select count(*) cnt from table t where t.a = x and t.b = y and t.c = z; if cnt = 0 then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания группового ограничения, можно использовать конструкцию вида

```
ALTER TABLE someTable ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3);
```

Это указывает, что комбинация значений в указанных столбцах уникальна для всей таблицы, хотя по отдельности столбцы не обязательно должны быть (и обычно не являются) уникальными.

[Описание в доке в разделе 5.4.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_3);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]